# Reset the request permission dialog on Marshmallow

Tags: permissions, 6.0-marshmallow

I am testing my Android application and trying to make sure all permissions (whether granted or denied) are handled correctly. I mistakenly clicked "Never ask again" on a permission and now it never asks me.

I have tried **Settings - Apps - Reset App Preferences**, but that didn't work.

How can I reset this so that the request permission dialog box comes up again for the permission?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to manually allow the permission on that specific app to reset the request permission dialog.

1. Open the **App info** (either by dragging from app launcher, or **Settings - Apps - [app name]**)
2. Select **Permissions**
3. Enable the permission you denied with "never ask again"
4. (Optional) Disable it again from here; note that by this time, your app will request the permission again when needed.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I've tested it and it does not work. It appears it's an Android bug: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/WjO0Sz5N-ew;context-place=forum/Nexus

Answer (score 2):

You can also uninstall and reinstall.

The accepted answer is of course correct, but as an Android developer, you probably know how to `adb uninstall <package>` / `adb install <apk>` faster than navigating through settings.